# How can I set the papersize in in book documentclass?

Tags: margins, paper-size

I need to create a document in book document class with papersize 170 x240, left and right margins 2 cm, top margin 2.2 cm and bottom margin 1.8 cm. I used this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,openright,twoside]{book}


\usepackage[width=170.00mm, height=240.00mm, left=2.0cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.2 cm, bottom=1.80cm]{geometry}
```

but now the printer is telling me that is 176 x 250. What should I change?

Comment: I believe it's `\usepackage[paperwidth=170.00mm, paperheight=240.00mm, ...` rather than just `width` and `height`... Anyway, it doesn't make sense to specify `b5paper` and then set up a different paper size.

Comment: `width = textwidth +marginparsep +marginparwidth <paperwidth=width+left+right` and 
`height = textheight +headheight + headsep + footskip<paperheight= height+top+bottom`

Comment: @yo' An answer, please...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting up the wrong key for `geometry`. The keys you want are `paperwidth` and `paperheight`.

However, I do not see the point in first specifying `[b5paper]` to the class, when you later change the size to something else in `geometry`.

The option `b5paper` has no effect and only makes your code unclear.