# What is the size of book?

Tags: book-design

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[azerbaijani]{babel}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.7cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{systeme}
```

I wrote my (math) book in native language by using packages above. Now how can I define the size of this book? Is it A4 or A5 or 24x17? I just use only {book} code. If I change this for example enter some size then my writing diffuses.

What is your suggestion? Thank you so much

Comment: Duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262449/166422

Comment: @DavidCarlisle   I got it thanks so much USA letter size  is 21.59x 27.94

Answer (score 2):

As you have not used `\documentclass[a4paper]` the paper size is the USA letter size. (So it will not print well on any normal paper size available elsewhere).

Comment: Actually, I believe it uses the dafault paper size that has been selected during the instalation of latex (say, texlive, miktex, mactex, etc). In my computer, for example, I have selected a4paper as default in my texlive instalation. Therefore, if nothing is specfied on \documentclass, latex should use a4paper.

Comment: @Fabricio no, that's not how it works.

Comment: You are right. I had, actually, never tested it. I assumed that since there is such option, it ought to be used this way.